# Flash problem in Delphi application

Tags: flash, delphi

I create Delphi application with Flash and everything was perfect before today day. Now when i start this project it send me a error.
If i try to add shockwave component to another project it gives me

```
ERROR
Class not registered ?
```

What does it mean?

Comment: Please do not yell. We can hear you pretty well from right there.

Comment: What component are you using?

Comment: What did you change on your machine to break it?

Comment: I use TShockwaveflash component ...

Comment: Something changed. You just don't know what. Or do you think your computer is feeling whimsical?

Comment: Navigate to '..system32\macromed\flash\', and try registering the 'flash???.ocx' there.

Answer (score 2):

Educated guess: you upgraded Flash, Air, or installed something else that upgrades Flash or Air.

In addition to that, you probably referenced a GUID for an old version of the COM object for Flash.

The result is that your app doesn't see the version of Flash that is currently installed.

I had a similar thing at a client a while ago when they called for my help: They had a hard reference to MSXML 6, then their test equipment had only MSXML 3 installed. Boom!

The first step was to use the generic MSXML COM GUID, it messed up because MSXML 3 had the base of search results off by one (either 1-based or 0-based, or the other way around, I forgot).

Final solution was to also make sure they were running a minimum version of MSXML (like already described in the test requirements).

You should sort out which version of the Flash you need as a minimum, and which GUID you must reference to instantiate the COM objects.

--jeroen

Answer (score 1):

Try to register the flash Activex control again on your machine then re-import the activex from delphi and create you own Wrapper component.